# How to save images to Room Persistence Library

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, android-image

Originally I was adding information (Strings) and a photo (from drawable) to card views. I had it working from a list and adding it to the cards within a recycler view using an adapter and such. Now I'm trying to migrate to saving this information using the Room Persistence Library and instead of adding dummy info in the code I am going to make it come from user input, as I'm trying to implement this I have discovered that saving images to Room DB is not too easy. The strings are working fine now I just need a way to save the images after taken from the camera.

I can't store images in the Room DB using types Image, Bitmap, URI, Drawables.

```java
@Entity(tableName = "machines_table")
public class Machines {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private Drawable photoId;
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Machines(String name, String location, Drawable photoId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.photoId = photoId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public Drawable getPhotoId() {
        return photoId;
    }

}
```

I guess I expected to be able to save images more easily however this is not the case when using any of the types I listed above I am given this error.

"error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll probably are able to save them as `byte[]`, however it is generally regarded as unwise to save bitmaps to the DB. Store them to the filesystem and save the filename (a UUID based one for example) to the DB. Then retrieve the file when needed.

The database would become huge and slow if it stores the images themselves.

Comment: Saving them to the filesystem would I be able to implement accounts logins eventually making the images and other information appear on other devices? Would this fall under the Autobackup? Or would it just be saved to the device with no option for syncing between devices

Answer (score 3):

you can not store pure image, have many options to store image:

1. convert image to base64 and store in database
2. save in local storage and store Uri in database
3. get image URL from server and store URL in database

Comment: Which of these options do you think would work best if I wanted to be able to save these per account eventually I plan on implementing that at some point so that I can pull this information up with a login on multiple devices. Saving them locally would it be backed up by Android's auto backup making this possible? I'm very new to all of this they offer one class on mobile development at my University which I'm wait listed for on my last semester. However even talking to friends who have taken it they have no clue what I'm doing. Don't really have anyone else to ask as I continue to research.

Comment: if pull info from the server my suggestion use the third option, get image URL from server and store URL in the database and load image use glide or picasso or etc, with saved URL per account

Comment: I've looked into using Picasso and glide, the cards that I use are created from user input in a create "Machine" page and I'll have the photo being pulled from gallery or taken from the camera. So what you're saying is I'll need to upload that to a server that's separate from the database, and save that url in the database. Is this sort of thing what like AWS or GCP is used for? Or would I have to host it on my own? something I'd rather not do at the time if possible. Which platform is best to use when implementing it for Android? Assuming GCP but I'm not entirely sure that it can do this

Comment: ok, you can not save the original image in a database for sending later to a server, you must be immediately sent the image to a server after user selected or taken a photo. so getting a successful result after upload image in a server update user info for showing a user avatar and in this step, you can save image URL

Answer (score 2):

You should use Converters class in room DB

```
class Converters {

@TypeConverter
fun fromBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap):ByteArray{
    val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
    return  outputStream.toByteArray()
}


@TypeConverter
fun toBitmap(byteArray: ByteArray):Bitmap{
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0, byteArray.size)
}
```

}

On DB:

```
@Database(entities = [Student::class, Note::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class StudentDatabase :RoomDatabase(){

abstract fun studentDao():StudentDAO
...
```

On Model:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "studentBitmap")
val studentBitmap:Bitmap?,
```