# How can I retrieve an image using shared presences and show it in an image view in Android studio?

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I'm trying to set an image in an image view in my activity but I don't know what the code is to do it.

I know how to do it but setting text into text view using this code

```
TextViewUser.setText( sharedaPrefManager.getInstance(this, ).get Username ().
```

I need how to do it but for an image.

I'm using volley and already get the image but I don't know how to put it in image view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `using volley` has nothing to do with `sharedaPrefManager`. How do you get it with `volley`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save images to Room Persistence Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117262/how-to-save-images-to-room-persistence-library)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the image URL load it to the ImageView as follows

Try picasso library

Add to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Then

```
String imageUrl = "https://example.com/someimage.png"

Picasso.get().load(imageUrl)
         .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting an image URL

so simply Use Glide

add this line to your app level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

then Use something like this

```
// String imgUrl = ImageURL;

String imgUrl = sharedaPrefManager.getInstance(this).getImgae();



Glide.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
```